# magento2 js owlCarousel not working

Tags: magento2.3

i have code

```
<?php
$filter = 'hompage_feature_2';
$product = $block->getProductCollectionHomepage($filter);
$items = [];
foreach($product as $value){
$items[] = $value;
}
$type = 'widget-new-grid';
?>
<div class="homepage_product_featured_2">
<ul class="product_featured_2">
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($product);$i++) : ?>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="image">
            <?php
            $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                ->init($items[$i], 'product_base_image')
                ->constrainOnly(true)
                ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                ->keepTransparency(true)
                ->keepFrame(true)
                ->resize(150, 150)->getUrl();
            ?>
            <a href="<?= $block->getProductUrl($items[$i]); ?>"><?php echo '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '">';  ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="information">
            <a href="<?= $block->getProductUrl($items[$i]); ?>"><p class="name"><?php echo $items[$i]['name']; ?></p></a>
            <p class="short-desc"><?= $block->shortenText($items[$i]['short_description']) ?></p>
            <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml($items[$i],$type); ?>
            <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/additional_info.phtml')->setProduct($items[$i])->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endfor ?>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery",
    'owl_carousel',
], function($) {
    $('.product_featured_2').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        loop:true,
        margin: 10,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplaySpeed: 300,
        slideTransition: 'linear',
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" 
aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    });
});
</script>
```

i want to use owlCarousel js to creat slider product but it not working. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
<?php
$filter = 'hompage_feature_2';
$product = $block->getProductCollectionHomepage($filter);
$items = [];
foreach($product as $value){
$items[] = $value;
}
$type = 'widget-new-grid';
?>
<div class="homepage_product_featured_2 owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">   
        <ul id="product_featured_2">
            <?php for($i=0;$i<count($product);$i++) : ?>
            <li class="item">
                <div class="image">
                    <?php
                    $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                        ->init($items[$i], 'product_base_image')
                        ->constrainOnly(true)
                        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
                        ->keepTransparency(true)
                        ->keepFrame(true)
                        ->resize(150, 150)->getUrl();
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?= $block->getProductUrl($items[$i]); ?>"><?php echo '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '">';  ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="information">
                    <a href="<?= $block->getProductUrl($items[$i]); ?>"><p class="name"><?php echo $items[$i]['name']; ?></p></a>
                    <p class="short-desc"><?= $block->shortenText($items[$i]['short_description']) ?></p>
                    <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml($items[$i],$type); ?>
                    <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/additional_info.phtml')->setProduct($items[$i])->toHtml(); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endfor ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery",
    'owl_carousel',
], function($,owlCarousel) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#product_featured_2').owlCarousel({
            items:5,
            loop:true,
            margin: 10,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 3000,
            autoplaySpeed: 300,
            slideTransition: 'linear',
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **owlcarousel** instead of **owl_carousel**.

Your code should:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "jquery",
    'owlcarousel',
], function($) {
    $('.product_featured_2').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        loop:true,
        margin: 10,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        autoplaySpeed: 300,
        slideTransition: 'linear',
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" 
aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    });
});
</script>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            owlcarousel: 'Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel'
        }
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are only passing in the jQuery dollar sign alias:

```
function($)
```

You need to also pass in the owlCarousel alias:

```
function($, owlCarousel)
```